# Normalizer in matrix groups

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have the problem of calculating the normalizer of
$\begin{bmatrix}
     \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{- 1}
\end{bmatrix} $
in the group
$\begin{bmatrix}
     \cos (\theta) & -\sin (\theta) \\ \sin (\theta) & \cos (\theta)
\end{bmatrix} $

this, to solve the problem of:

For all $ g \in SL_2 (\mathbb {R}) $ there is a decomposition $ g = \begin{bmatrix}
     \cos (\theta_1) & -\sin (\theta_1) \\ \sin (\theta_1) & \cos (\theta_1)
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
     \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{- 1}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
     \cos (\theta_2) & -\sin (\theta_2) \\ \sin (\theta_2) & \cos (\theta_2)
\end{bmatrix} $ which is unique except conjugation by elements of the normalizer.

I know that the normalizer $ N $ is generated by $ N = \langle \begin {bmatrix}
     0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end {bmatrix} \rangle $

I was able to show $ \langle \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \rangle \subseteq N $

Does anyone have an idea of how to show the other contention?

Comment: The normlizer of a single matrix is the same as its centralizer. Is that what you meant to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly by definition. Write $R(\theta)$ for your rotation matrix. You need
$$
R(\theta)\begin{bmatrix} \lambda&0\\0&\lambda^{-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda^{-1}\end{bmatrix} R(\theta). 
$$
This is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda \cos (\theta) & -\lambda^{-1}\sin (\theta) \\ \lambda\sin (\theta) & \lambda^{-1}\cos (\theta)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
     \lambda\cos (\theta) & -\lambda\sin (\theta) \\ \lambda^{-1}\sin (\theta) & \lambda^{-1}\cos (\theta)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The diagonal entries give you nothing, they are always equal. The non-diagonal entries give you the equality 
$$\tag1
\lambda\sin\theta=\lambda^{-1}\sin\theta. 
$$
So, if $\lambda=\pm1$, then any $\theta $ works and the normalizer consists of all matrices in the group. When $\lambda^2\ne1$, the equality in $(1)$ forces $\sin\theta=0$, so $\theta=0$ and the normalizer is $\{I\}$.

Comment: Isn't this the centraliser rather than the normaliser?

Comment: Yes and no. The question is not clear, my understanding was that it is about a single matrix. After seeing your question maybe OP meant the set of all such matrices.